# Excel 2016 VBA force save to .xlsm - How to save the template?

Tags: excel, vba, templates, save

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim fname As Variant, DateTime As String, myInitialFilename As String
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
SaveAsUI = True
If SaveAsUI Then


    Cancel = True   'Cancel the original SaveAs

    DateTime = "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyy_mm_dd_hhmmss") '= " [yyyy_mm_dd]"
    'DateTime = " [" & Format(Now(), "yyyy_mm_dd  hhmm_ss") & "]" '= " [yyyy_mm_dd  hhmm_ss]" (use instead if you want time in the name)
    myInitialFilename = "Quote" 'EDIT THIS

     'Get filename (with path) for saving
    fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=myInitialFilename & DateTime, fileFilter:="Excel Marcro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm),*.xlsm")
    If fname = False Then Exit Sub  'Exit if user hit Cancel
    Application.EnableEvents = False  'Prevent this event from firing
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=52
      '52 = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = xlsm (with macro's in 2007-2010)
    Application.EnableEvents = True  'Re-enable events
End If
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
Application.EnableEvents = True
MsgBox "An error occured during save." & Err.Number, vbCritical, "Error"
End Sub`
```

I have written a bit of VBA code to force a save or save-as to be the file type .xlsm, which works fine.  However, I can't seem to save the template file with the VBA code in it because of the code itself forcing the .xlsm save.
I have a template saved without the code, but as soon as I add the code, obviously I can no longer save as xltm, since the code pushes to save as xslm.  Looking for a best practice solution to save my template!

Thanks,
Kathy B.

Comment: Best to include your code.

Comment: if fileType <> .xlt?

Answer (score 0):

Any changes within the file will either make it always save as xltm, or always as xlsm.  So you want a flag stored in a different file, which defaults to false.  This way, when you want to edit your template, you can turn it on and save your changes, but in normal usage, it will save as .xlsm.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not overwrite the SaveAsUI-Flag with true
you can save the file as Template when you work on it.
If you create a new File form the Template the
SaveAsUI-Flag will be true and then your code forces
to keep the macros.